# New alternative to the Gof design pattern book for uml MDD with C++

Tags: c++, uml, design-patterns, mdd

I am using lately a tool i.e. Rhapsody for MDD with C++ and I have difficulties on coding the classes by beginning with the uml diagram. Simultaneously I am trying to integrate some of the Gof book examples in the UML diagram and somehow it confuses me....

> Is there any book that 1) is quite new
>   (gof is 1994..) 2)
>   describes/introduces MMD using C++
>   combined with design patterns usage 3)
>   provides illustrated uml examples
>   accompanied by c++ source code

Note1: My local library has some books but for java.. But even though both languages are object oriented, I think that the uml diagrams are not the same because of different features between the 2 languages e.g interfaces modelling

Note2: If u know a good site with good resources on the subject instead of a book please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Maybe MDD is just not the proper approach for you? (I know it ain't for me)
Patterns are straight-foward time-tested solutions for common design problems. You use them when you need them, not just to use them anyway.

Maybe better describe your actual goal rather than what you believe to be the way to your goal?

Answer (score 4):

[**Head First Design Patterns**](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126/) is the book that I first used to learn design patterns.
It is definitely a lot easier to start learning design patterns with that the GoF book. After I understood it the GoF book wasn't that difficult to read but I can understand if you found it dry as a beginner.